# Loading related data in Entity Framework Core and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to load related data with `Include()` but I think I'm doing something wrong.

I want to load the shoe's images on this table and the images for practice purposes in one row, but when I add the `ShoeImages.ImageURL` (to give an example) I get an error CS1061 and I'm not able to show the data from the `Include()`.

I have an index page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Shoes.Data.Entities.ShoeEntity>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShoesImages)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <!--- This is the problem too --->
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShoesImages.ImageURL)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Index controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
     var data = _context.Shoes.Include(ci => ci.ShoeImages);
     return View(data);
}
```

`Shoe` entity:

```
public class ShoeEntity
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public ICollection<ShoeImageEntity> ShoeImages { get; set; }
}
```

ShoeImages entity:

```
public class ShoeImageEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ImageURL { get; set; }

    public string ImageFullPath => 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageURL) ? null : $"https://localhost:44357{ImageURL.Substring(1)}";

    public ShoeEntity Shoe { get; set; }
}
```

Context class:

```
public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<UserEntity, RoleEntity, string>
{
     public DbSet<ShoeEntity> Shoes{ get; set; }
     public DbSet<ShoeImagesEntity> ShoesImages { get; set; }     

     public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
     {
     }
}
```

Also I tried the Entity Framework documentation.

Comment: Please post your context class.

Comment: Added the context class to my post. The database is clean and I'm using the basic settings to connect the database.

Comment: ShoesImages is a collection, which url do you want?

Comment: I can create shoes, save the images on wwwroot folder and then, get the url of this images but I still stuck on display the Shoes' data with the respective images or join them appropriately in a index page (using html) and can't even access to the ShoesImages properties.

I want to get the ImageURL.

Comment: But your ShoeImages is a collection, containing multiple rows. You'll need to loop through them or something.

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation I read, it is necessary but I cannot achieve how to add it in the ```return view()``` and show it in the view or even make it work

Comment: Are you still getting the CS1061 compile time error?

Comment: Yes, it's because I can't access the Shoes.ShoeImages.ImageURL property on the Index's view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your ShoeImages filed corresponds to multiple ImageURL fields because
>   it is of type    ICollection.

You can use the following view code to show them.

```html
@model IEnumerable<Shoes.Data.Entities.ShoeEntity>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShoesImages)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            foreach (var images in item.ShoeImages)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => images.ImageURL)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. If I had done it alone I would not have noticed. I check the answer as correct. I'll make an edit because both foreach requires @ before every foreach

```html
@model IEnumerable<Shoes.Data.Entities.ShoeEntity>
<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ShoesImages)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @foreach (var images in item.ShoeImages)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => images.ImageURL)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```